# Why is zlib.crc32 faster than binascii.crc32?

Tags: python

In the following benchmark, I find that the function `zlib.crc32` is about 2.5 times faster `binascii.crc32`. Why is that, and are there any downsides to using the `zlib` module's implementation?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import timeit

print("b:", timeit.timeit("binascii.crc32(data)", setup="import binascii, zlib; data=b'X'*4096", number=100000))
print("z:", timeit.timeit("zlib.crc32(data)",     setup="import binascii, zlib; data=b'X'*4096", number=100000))
```

Result:

```
b: 1.0176826480001182
z: 0.4006126120002591
```

Comment: The first thing I'd try to look at is the implementation: [binascii](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/binascii.c#L933) vs [zlib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/zlib/crc32.c). Funnily, `binascii` seems to be able to use `zlib`'s CRC32 as an option. Maybe the difference is how the accept the data from a Python string?

Answer (score 5):

I found this discussion:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-March/012728.html where Gregory P. Smith  (in a discussion with Guido) wrote:

> Removal from binascii would break things for platforms or embedded systems
> wanting crc32 that don't want to include zlib.  Anyone care?

**TL;DR**: The binascii implementation is for systems that don't have zlib (or don't want to include it), so it's considered sub-optimal, but would break things if removed.